# how to enable a menu item in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, rad-controls

How can I do this in ASP.NET?

```
main.Items[0].Enabled = false;
main.Items[1].Enabled = false;
folder.Items[0].Enabled = false;
folder.Items[1].Enabled = false;
```

Comment: I'm confused... If you disable the menu why do you expect them to be enabled?

Comment: i need role based enable disable the menu.

Comment: event if you disable menu and some one knows the url then he can hit that url directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to enable/disable menu items on role base then you can use  sitemap in your project and easily show hide menu according to user role.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode url="" roles="*">
    <!--<siteMapNode url="Default.aspx" title="Home" description="" roles="*" />-->
    <siteMapNode url="Dash.aspx" title="Dash" description="admin" roles="KAM,Admin,QMR"  />
    <siteMapNode url="~Manage.aspx" title="Complaint List"  description="" roles="Public,Admin"  />
    <siteMapNode url="~/Manage1.aspx" title="title1"  description="" roles="role1,Admin"  />
    <siteMapNode url="~/Manage2.aspx" title="title2"  description="" roles="role2,Admin" />
    <siteMapNode url="~/ManageUsers.aspx" title="Administration"  description="admin" roles="Admin"   />
    <siteMapNode url="" title="Reports"  description="admin" roles="Admin" >
      <siteMapNode url="Manage4.aspx" title="Manage123"  description="admin" roles="Admin"   />
      <siteMapNode url="Summary.aspx" title="Summary"  description="admin" roles="Admin"   />
    </siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

Comment: welcome,may it helps u